# Rule-based feed items

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

Can we have a rule-based feed - maybe constructed similarly to mail client rules: e.g. I would love something like:

when **a new question is posted** with tag **C#** and tag **multithreading** then post **question** to feed

Although, just implementing the questions matching the union of a set of tags would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe add support for multiple tags per filter to [this page](http://stackexchange.com/filters)?

Comment: There are RSS feeds for each tag; I'm not sure if any common RSS feed aggregation tools can provide this merging functionality on your behalf.